# Center div between two divs

Tags: html, css

How to center .middle div between two other divs? I tried margin: 0 auto; margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto; etc. But I can't achieve the right effect. This .middle div should be in between the two.

Go full screen to see what I mean.

Thank You.

```css
div {
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
    height: 52px;
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
    background-color: #B2D490;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10;
}
h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
    color: #00457D;
}
.left {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #C7E6FF;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 64px;
}
.middle {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #DEF0FF;
    margin-top: 64px;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #C7E6FF;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 64px;
}
#footer {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #57C449;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
p {
    color: #00579E;
}
#footer p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 35px;
}
span {
    color: #D4EBFF;
}
```

```html
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <title>My Resume</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="header">
     <h1>My <span>Resume</span></h1>
 </div>
 <div class="left">
     <h2>Left Column</h2>
         <ul>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
         </ul>
 </div>
  <div class="middle">
     <h2>Centered Center Column</h2>
         <ul>
                <li><p>Some Text</p></li>
                <li><p>Some Text</p></li>
                <li><p>Some Text</p></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
     <h4>Right Column</h4>
         <ul>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
        </ul>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both; border:none; border-radius: none;"></div>
 <div id="footer">
     <p>© 2015 Me - the Programmer</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using your HTML as given and using floats.

First, in `#header`, fix the syntax so that `top: 10px`, you need units (px).

Since your three `div`'s have known widths, you can take advantage of this with the `calc` CSS function to determine the right margin for `.left` as
follows:

```
margin-right: calc(50% - 300px);
```

The center of the page is at the 50% position.  Take away 200px for the width of the `.left` element, and then 100px for the half-width of the `.middle` element.  The net result is that the `.middle` element appears in the middle of the page, as you desired.

However, you may want to specify a min-width for the page otherwise the `.middle` element could overlap the `.left` if the page width is narrow enough.  Alternatively, take care of small screens using media queries.

(Note that I used widths of 200px instead of 300px so that the demonstration fitted in the small windows of the code editor.)

```css
div {
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
    height: 52px;
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
    background-color: #B2D490;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
}
h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
    color: #00457D;
}
.left {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #C7E6FF;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 64px;
    margin-right: calc(50% - 300px);
}
.middle {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #DEF0FF;
    margin-top: 64px;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #C7E6FF;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 64px;
}
#footer {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #57C449;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
p {
    color: #00579E;
}
#footer p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 35px;
}
span {
    color: #D4EBFF;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <title>My Resume</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="header">
     <h1>My <span>Resume</span></h1>
 </div>
 <div class="left">
     <h2>Left Column</h2>
         <ul>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
         </ul>
 </div>
  <div class="middle">
     <h2>Centered Center Column</h2>
         <ul>
                <li><p>Some Text</p></li>
                <li><p>Some Text</p></li>
                <li><p>Some Text</p></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
     <h4>Right Column</h4>
         <ul>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
             <p>Some Text</p>
        </ul>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both; border:none; border-radius: none;"></div>
 <div id="footer">
     <p>© 2015 Me - the Programmer</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank You! Everything works perfectly.
Although I assume you mean 300px (of which 150px is a half) not 200px.

Comment: @ArtemZ I fixed the numbers in my original post to make it consistent with the 200px widths.  In you case with 300px wide elements, the offset would be 450px (300 + 300/2). All the best!

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap your 3 containers into one and the use `flexbox`

Basically I added a container with a class `container-center`and this css:

```
.container-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

as in this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/fggd4qkm/1/)**

(I also removed the float from the `right`, `middle`, `left`)

Answer (score 4):

There is no really *easy* way to do this with floats **but** it's simpler if you wrap all the elements in a div (or other sectoning element) and use `flexbox`.

You should note however, that even with `flexbox` this requires that the two "side" elements have the same width.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EVjzjg) as the SO Snippets are of resticted width.

```css
div {
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 27px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
  color: #00457D;
}

main {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 64px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #C7E6FF;
}

.middle {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #DEF0FF;
}

.right {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #C7E6FF;
}

p {
  color: #00579E;
}

span {
  color: #D4EBFF;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="left">
    <h2>Left Column</h2>
    <ul>
      <p>Some Text</p>
      <p>Some Text</p>
      <p>Some Text</p>
      <p>Some Text</p>
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <h2>Centered Center Column</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>Some Text</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Some Text</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Some Text</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h4>Right Column</h4>
    <ul>
      <p>Some Text</p>
      <p>Some Text</p>
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .middle {
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #DEF0FF;
    margin-top: 64px;
}
```

This is what you are looking for?

Comment: margin: auto; should horizontally center an element within its container.
If i remember right.

Comment: If the op doesn't want my answer the op can just choose not mark it as an answer. I just know that margin:auto is centering the element. You do not have to be a smartass about it :-)